# Issue making CSS responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the below CSS responsive, specifically so it works on a phone screen.

I assume it is because the dimensions of the books sides are given in px (I haven't included this bit of CSS), but I thought it would be able to be resolved with vh / vw in or a % in the div.

Please see code below:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotatingAnimationX {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
            transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
            transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotatingAnimationX {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
            transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
            transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotatingAnimationY {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotatingAnimationY {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotatingAnimationZ {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotatingAnimationZ {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

.containerp {
  /*width: 100vw;*/
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /*display: flex;*/
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.containerp > div {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.boockup {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(29deg) rotateY(-88deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(29deg) rotateY(-88deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
.book-container {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: 30s rotatingAnimationY linear infinite;
  animation: 30s rotatingAnimationY linear infinite;
}
.book-container > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make it responsive you will need to use:

Percentages
vw ( viewport width)
vh. ( viewport height) 
And also @media() (media queries)

A trick I have found is if you want to keep things to scale is to use vw for both width and height.
For example: 
You have an image which is 600 px wide, and 150px high.

```
.image{
  height: 150px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

// the above would display the image as 600 x 150 px

```
@media( max-width: 600px){
  .image{
    width:100vw;
    height: 25vw;
   }
}
```

// when you’re screen size gets below 600px wide the image would change to 100vw x 25 vw keeping the same scale of 4:1.